# DataPusher is unable to connect to CKAN 2.8

Tags: amazon-web-services, ckan

DataPusher is not working with my CKAN 2.8 install. I have DataPusher and CKAN on the same VPS (an Amazon EC2 instance). I cannot curl /api/3/action/resource_show from within the instance, but I can from outside it at the same IP address I can access the CKAN web gui from. I am using the default port settings/followed the official CKAN documentation for setting up CKAN and DataPusher/DataStore.

Upon checking the error logs (specifically datapusher.error.log in /var/log/apache2) the latest message is:

`ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='{ckan.site_url value, in this case the public IP of the instance}', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/3/action/resource_show (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f3bb0151490>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue but I used a different approach to solve it.

The system looks up DNS names in  the /etc/hosts file before it goes to the external DNS server. I simply pointed my hostname (from the URL) to the local IP address like so:

172.16.22.2        ckan.installation.url

This way, the server connects to itself when it needs to reach ckan.installation.url and users connect to ckan.installation.url (public facing IP) when they need to access the site.

Comment: D'oh. This would be the "efficient" solution, and how one would "point" a server's hostname to itself without it going "outside" the server and then back in. Thank you!

Comment: No, thank you, @jspinella! Your answer led to my solution. I use a proper virtual machine in a data centre where I have no control over the firewall that NATs my private IP to public IP address and vice versa. Once a google search turned up your answer, being a DNS buff, I knew where to go. Thank you for sharing! By the way, in my case the Error was "connection refused" because no web listener on the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately the issue is that with an AWS EC2 VPS, your Ubuntu instance is not aware of its public-facing IP address, which is probably what you're using to reach the CKAN web gui hosted on said VPS.

Ideally the CKAN API can be hit internally but I have been unable to do so with localhost/127.0.0.1 in place of the VPS's external/public-facing IP address. The issue with setting the ckan site_url to localhost is that is what you will be directed to from the CKAN web gui when attempting to use DataPusher (e.g. manually initiating upload of a resource to the DataStore). Your computer obviously won't know localhost refers to the CKAN dev server... So in short, the ckan site_url value must be something accessible by both DataPusher and people/devices on the public Internet (assuming you want your CKAN instance to be publicly-accessible).

The solution here is to open port 80 to the **public IP address** of the AWS EC2 instance in the inbound rules of the instance's security group. In other words, you are letting the instance hit *itself* at port 80. Seem inefficient, but I don't have an alternative at the moment. It's better than nothing!